# how to select from many tables

Tags: mysql

I want merge the selection of 5 tables in example i mean if i have video and articles and images and etc tables and want to make a search i want merge the search result in one query with multiple select from.

Comment: you want to search in all the tables for the same string??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example

```
   SELECT v.image,a.text FROM video as v JOIN article as a ON v.id=a.id WHERE ...
```

Add as many tables as necessary, and from the SELECT you take only the relevant fields.

The only difficulty is to make appropriate JOIN, i.e. find the relevant fields in all tables for the JOIN (and/or WHERE) in order for the query to return unique rows.

Comment: You better be aliasing video as v and article as a if you plan to use them in the statement as such.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check out [SQL Joins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29)

Answer (score 1):

Try here [MySQL Reference Manual - Join Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)